# Appending data after the result of union of select queries

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table which returns path and select queries(**result1**)....

I want to get the result of the union of select queries along with relative paths...Make sure that I dnt want to store result1 in any table..

I want only a single select query..

For more clearity of the problem, I am giving the example...

I have a table named table1 which has stored path and queries like below

Now I fire the select queries and get the result like this:

```
Path      | Query
page1     | select name from table2
page2     | select name from table3
page3     | select name from table4
```

What I want is the result of union of all queries must be appended with their relative paths, so expected result will be like this:

```
path      |   result of queries
page1     |   first query's result
page2     |   second query's result
page3     |   third query's result
```

So in short I want to append data ( in this scenario) with the result of union queries related to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward, just use an fake field in the select:

```
select
    'page1' as Path
    col1,
    col2
from
    table1
union all
select
    'page2' as Path
    col1,
    col2
from
    table2
union all
select
    'page3' as Path
    col1,
    col2
from
    table3
```

and bingo, you have your data, you have your "appended" as you call it data and everyone lived happily ever after.

Edit: Unless there is something identifiable in the query which can be used to identify where it came from, you can't do this without modifying the queries. If there is something, ANYTHING in the query (even if not exactly what you want) then you can use the union query as a subquery and join to it from a static query or a CTE:

```
select
    p1
    c1,
    c2
from
    (
    select
        col1,
        col2,
        somethingUnique
    from
        table1
    union all
    select
        col1,
        col2,
        somethingUnique
    from
        table2
    union all
        select
        col1,
        col2,
        somethingUnique
    from
        table3
    ) subby
        join (
            select
                'Page1' as p1,
                uniqueToTable1 as identy
            from
                dual
            union all
            select
                'Page2' as p1,
                uniqueToTable2 as identy
            from
                dual
            union all
            select
                'Page3' as p1,
                uniqueToTable3 as identy
            from
                dual
            ) pages
                on subby.somethingUnique=pages.identy
    )
```

If whatever is unique to each table (assuming it is there) is fairly static, you could get away using a simple case statement in your outer query instead of joining to a static select.

Edit 2:

I did think of one more way this could be achieved, but running the queries individually as a subquery the unioning the output (it's ugly, but it's at least possible:

```
select
    'page1' as page
    col1,
    col2
from
    (
        select
            col1,
            col2
        // etc your first query that you would union
    )
union all
select
    'page2' as page
    col1,
    col2
from
    (
        select
            col1,
            col2
        // etc your second query that you would union
    )
// and so on...
```

Comment: Nope, that is not I want... Queries I got in the result query must not be editable...

Comment: See edit. If that won't work, it can't really be done.

Comment: @samkitshah I ended up thinking of one more (horrid) way of doing it, but thought I would add it in case it helped anyone else that might come along and see this question.